# Can't refresh database model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6.1

I can't refresh database model. I am using Asp .net 5.

This is a short example of what I done:

1.Create class person in "person.cs" file, which is inside "Model" directory.

```
namespace MyWeb.Models
{
    public class person
    {
        public int personID { get; set; }
        public string login { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2. Create myContext.cs file in Models directory.

```
namespace MyWeb.Models
{
    public class myContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<person> persons { get; set; }
    }
}
```

3.Create myInitializer.cs inside Models directory

```
namespace MyWeb.Models
{
    public class myInitializer :DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<myContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(myContext context)
        {
            var persons= new List<person>
            {
                new person{ login = "me", name = "meme", password = "abc", surname = "abc" },
                new person{ login = "me2", name = "meme2", password = "abc2", surname = "abc2" }
            };
            foreach (var p in persons)
            {
                context.persons.Add(p);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

4.Inside Global.asax.cs add following line = Database.SetInitializer(new myInitializer())

```
namespace MyWeb
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<myContext>(new myInitializer());
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

After first run everything was working fine, database was created, records was added to database, but when model has been changed database don't reload. I search on the web about this but nothing helps.

How I can refresh database model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Enable-Migrations` command, then `Add-Migration "description of changes"` and finally `Update-Database` from the package manager console